# R: remove leap day by calculating mean with previous day

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, leap-year

I have a timeseries of which the following is a subset:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16851, 16852, 16853, 16854, 
16855, 16856, 16857, 16858, 16859, 16860), class = "Date"), BAL = c(4.38212529123126, 
6.2362101768993, 7.58042025123348, 1.28668112319138, 0.394057913904365, 
0.223231297328036, -0.677870337868538, -0.803250821089761, -0.812567723037268, 
-0.586754184659877)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In order to have the same amount of days for each year, I need to remove the 29th February. I could easily do this by:

```
library(lubridate, dplyr)
filter(x, !(month(Date) == 2 & day(Date) == 29))
```

But then I would lose the measured information of that day. My idea is to replace the measurement of the 28th February with the mean of the 28th and 29th February, but I have no idea how I could do this. Please note that my original timeseries is much longer and consists of several years of measurements.

Comment: Why do you want the same amount of days for each year?

Comment: @Hugh I am calculating the empirical distribution per day for multiple years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the base R code below

```
idx <- with(df,which(format(Date,"%m-%d")=="02-29"))
within(df,BAL <- replace(BAL,idx-1,mean(BAL[idx+(-1:0)])))[-idx,]
```

which gives

```
  Date          BAL
  <date>      <dbl>
1 2016-02-20  4.38
2 2016-02-21  6.24
3 2016-02-22  7.58
4 2016-02-23  1.29
5 2016-02-24  0.394
6 2016-02-25  0.223
7 2016-02-26 -0.678
8 2016-02-27 -0.803
9 2016-02-28 -0.700
```